# Why does the server hang for GAE php8.2 standard environment when echoing a long string?

Tags: php, macos, google-app-engine, firefox, safari

Am I doing something wrong or is this a server problem?  This hangs up the browser (Safari and Firefox under MACOS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?php
$qq = str_repeat("X",409998);  
echo $qq;
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Running on Google's AppEngine, standard environment, PHP 8.2.  If I shorten the string, it works fine.  While the problem is consistent, if I play with the length of the string, I can get it to work with some longer strings.

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: Server waits about 3 minutes and then times out:
INFO 2024-01-14T22:12:41.591151Z [pid1] Sending terminated signal to processes [session:RHKG18C]
INFO 2024-01-14T22:12:41.590782Z [pid1] Received terminated signal [session:RHKG18C]

Comment: Further testing rules out the browsers:  I can add a 410K string into the HTML and it works fine.  If I assign the same string to a PHP variable and then instruct it to echo the value, it hangs up. Also, the code works under php 5 but not php 8.2.  Lastly, if I use a 205k string and echo it twice, the browser still hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

I am downloading images from Google Cloud Storage using the "gs:" wrapper, and the data is used as the "src" for an image (hence the need to "echo" a large file).

Here's a workaround until the problem can be resolved: use Ajax and JSON to download the file a chunk at a time and then reconstruct the file in the HTML file.  Set the chunk size to something that doesn't hang up the browser.

source.php

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$chunk_size = 300000;   //multiple of 3 because base64 works with groups of 3 bytes

$chunk = $_REQUEST['chunk'];
if($chunk == 0) {   // first request for file
   $required_chunks = ceil(filesize("gs://$_REQUEST[key]") / $chunk_size);
   if($required_chunks == 1) {    // send complete file
   $data="data:$_REQUEST[content_type];base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents("gs://$_REQUEST[key]"));
        echo json_encode(array($_REQUEST['target'],$data,0));
    }
    else {      // file must be sent in chunks                $data="data:$_REQUEST[content_type];base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents("gs://$_REQUEST[key]",FALSE,NULL,0,$chunk_size));
            echo json_encode(array($_REQUEST['target'],$data,1,$required_chunks,$_REQUEST['key']));
        }
    }
    else {  // continue sending chunks
        $data=base64_encode(file_get_contents("gs://$_REQUEST[key]",FALSE,NULL,$chunk * $chunk_size,$chunk_size));
        echo json_encode(array($_REQUEST['target'],$data,++$chunk,$_REQUEST['required_chunks'],$_REQUEST['key']));
   }
}
?>
```

receiver.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
data_cache=[]

function getImage(target,type,k) {
    var xmlhttp
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var d=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
            if(d[2] == 0) document.getElementById(d[0]).src=d[1]   // single chunk
            else {
                if(d[2]!=d[3]) { // not the last chunk
                    if(d[2] == 1) data_cache[d[0]] = d[1]   // start cache
                    else {
                        data_cache[d[0]] = data_cache[d[0]] + d[1]           //append to cache
                    }
                    // send for next chunk
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","source.php?target="+d[0]+"&key="+d[4]+"&chunk="+d[2]+"&required_chunks="+d[3])
                    xmlhttp.send()
                }
                else {
                    dc = data_cache[d[0]] + d[1]
                    document.getElementById(d[0]).src = dc
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET","source.php?target="+target+"&content_type="+type+"&key="+k+"&chunk=0")
    xmlhttp.send()
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV><IMG id='i999'><SCRIPT>getImage('i999','image/jpeg',{bucket}/{file}.jpg')</SCRIPT></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```